# The new unary operator in terms of implies and negation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let us define a new unary operator $\models$ as follows
$\mathcal{T}[|\models\phi |]_\tau = 1$ if $\phi$ is tautology and 0 otherwise.
As $\{\rightarrow,\neg\}$ is a functionally complete set, how de we write the unary operator $\models$ in terms of these two operators.

Comment: I think you are conflating propositions and their logical operators ($\rightarrow,\neg$) with truth value assignments such as $\mathcal{T}$ defined above.  While such assignments, in connection with "truth tables", allow us to decide which formulas of propositional logic are *tautologies*, the logical operators are syntactical elements of propositional logic, not themselves assignment operators.

Comment: I was asking if there is any proposition in terms of $\phi,\rightarrow and \neg$ which is logically equivalent to $\models\phi$.

Comment: What you say about $\models\phi$ tells us that even if $\phi$ has propositional variables appearing in it, $\models\phi$ does not.  So this isn't a "unary operator" in the syntax of propositional logic, and there's no reason to think an appeal to "a functionally complete set" of syntactic operators will allow us to "write the unary operator $\models\phi$ in terms of these".

Comment: @PraneethKacham What hardmath says is exactly correct: your $\vDash$ is not an operator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that by "logically equivalent" you mean two formulas whose two-sided implication can be proven in propositional logic, and that you are asking for formula involving $\phi,\lnot,\rightarrow$ only that works whenever $\phi$ is replaced by a syntactically valid formula.

Then it cannot be done.  While $\models\phi$ as you've defined it has no propositional variables appearing in it, any syntactically valid combination of $\phi, \lnot, \rightarrow$ will contain all the propositional variables that $\phi$ does.

For convenience in proving such a syntactical construction $P(\phi)$ does not exist, recall that $P(\phi)$ and $\models\phi$ are equivalent iff they have the same truth tables.

To give a specific example, consider $\phi = p$, a non-tautologous propositional formula consisting of a single variable.  Under a liberal interpretation of your definition, $\models\phi$ is then "falsehood" (sometimes the notation $\bot$ is used, as $\top$ is used for truth).

But $p \iff \bot$ is not a theorem of the propositional calculus, e.g. because the truth table for $p$ has both truth and falsehood, while the truth table for $\bot$ consists only of falsehood entries.

More generally a formula $P(\phi)$ whose truth table values do not depend on the variable(s) in $\phi$ will either be all truth or all falsehood.  If $\phi$ is not a tautology, then we need all values to be falsehood, but if $\phi$ is a tautology, we need all values to be truth.  Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.